# Comparing values difficulty with counter

Tags: java

I am reading a text and calculating how many times this value has occurred in the text. To do this I am using an ArrayList, whenever more than one character of the same type is added which is already in my ArrayList....I increment a counter. So at the end of the method I'm able to print the letters of the alphabet contained within the text matching with it's corresponding occurrence.

```
for(int i; i < text.length i++)
  counter = 0
  if arraylist already contains the character then continue
  otherwise add the character to the array
   for j; j < text.length j++
     if index of text(j) and text(i) == the same
         counter++

       system out print arraylist[i] + counter
```

This is pseudo code to give you an idea of how my program works, I don't want to post the actual code up as it is assessed and I'm conscious about people using it.

So, I'm looking for a way to identify how to find the highest and lowest letters which have occurred. I'm struggling for ideas unless I pass on both the counter and index of array list character to some sort of data structure such as a hashmap =/ I feel like I must really be overthinking it though, unless the way I've structured my program isn't the best for what I'm trying to do. Because obviously I can't compare the counters each loop? .... questioning whether having a hashmap may be better and worth restarting everything.

Anyway, any suggestions welcome! ( this is assessed so please don't give an answer, but more of a possibility for how it could be approached )

Comment: Why not use a `HashMap` to begin with? Then you don't need a nested for loop...

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly, you want to print out how many times each character of the alphabet occurs within the text? If so, you should use a definitely use a hashmap. Pair each character with it's count. If you try to add a character to the map and it's already there, increment it's count. At the end, iterate through the hashmap with a loop, and record the min and max values.

Comment: Yeah think I've taken a really poor approach to this, will take your advise @EricGuan. Because I'll soon need to use the min/max in order to find the shift between the most common and least common alphabetical letters (E and Z)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a hashmap, i.e.

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> charMap;
```

Where the Integer is the count you would like to keep track of. Populate your hashmap with the appropriate characters. After, you can simply get the character by the get("somechar") method and increase the integer by 1.
After you're done iterating through the characters, you can iterate through the hashmap to determine the character with the lowest/highest frequency.